# Dúvida em usar checked="checked" em uma função jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Eu tenho um formulário e queria que quando a página fosse carregada, se meu checkbox estiver setado, desabilitasse a propriedade "disable" do formulário.

No exemplo do código abaixo, eu coloquei `checked="checked"` porém só funciona se eu clicar pra desabilitar e clicar de novo para habilitar.

Bem perdida nisso.

Poderiam me ajudar?

```js
$('#meuCheckbox').click(function() {
    $('#meuTexto').attr('disabled',! this.checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="meuTexto" /><input type="checkbox" id="meuCheckbox" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `$(document).ready(function() {});` que vai definir as ações quando terminar o carregamento da página.

```js
$('#meuCheckbox').click(function() {
    $('#meuTexto').attr('disabled', !this.checked)
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#meuTexto').attr('disabled', !$('#meuCheckbox').is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="meuTexto" />
<input type="checkbox" id="meuCheckbox" checked="checked" />
```